# Computing the KL divergence with kernel density estimates

Tags: r, numerical-integration, kernel-density

I have two vectors of varying length, and I want to compute the DKL from the density estimates using the `density()` function in R.

The equation of the DKL is the following.

[image]

I think I can use numerical integration, say

```
kde1 = density(x)
kde2 = density(y)
f1 = approxfun(kde1$x,kde1$y,rule=2)
f2 = approxfun(kde2$x,kde2$y,rule=2)
kde_f = function(f1,f2){
  f1 * log2(f1/f2)
}
```

Then integrate over `kde_f`, e.g.

`integrate(f = kde_f,lower=0, upper=100)`

Of course, this doesn't work, but I wrote this as the main idea of what I want to do. I don't have idea of how to proceed, or even if this have sense. Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I came to this solution

```
kld_base = function(x,y,...){
  integrand = function(x,y,t){
    f.x =  approx(density(x)$x,density(x)$y,t)$y
    f.y =  approx(density(y)$x,density(y)$y,t)$y
    tmpRatio = f.x *(log2(f.x) - log2(f.y))
    tmpRatio = ifelse(is.infinite(tmpRatio),0,ifelse(is.na(tmpRatio),0,tmpRatio))
    return(tmpRatio)
  }
  return(integrate(integrand,-Inf,Inf,x = x,y = y,stop.on.error=FALSE)$value)
}

set.seed(13)
x = rnorm(100)
y = rnorm(100)
kld_base(x,y)
# [1] 0.06990757
```

I will let the question open for a while, if someone have a better solution than mine please feel free to comment.

Comment: Have you managed to implement JS divergence in a similar way ?

Comment: No, I haven't tried, but I think is easy to adapt the code for the JSD. Just define M=0.5*(P + Q). Then, JSD = 0.5*DKL(P||M) + 0.5*DKL(Q||M), where you can compute DKL with the `kld_base`