# KL Divergence with numerical integration vs 'kld' from knrumsey/quack do not agree

Tags: r

I am trying to verify that my KL divergence calculation is working, so I was trying to compare 2 different methods which should give similar enough results, but they don't, so something is off I assume.

The code below compares a numeric integration from [Computing the KL divergence with kernel density estimates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55604403/computing-the-kl-divergence-with-kernel-density-estimates), with that of the kld function from the knrumsey/quack package (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/637728/z-test-with-no-relevant-sample-size-as-i-have-a-gaussian-probability-distributio/637762?noredirect=1#comment1191976_637762).

An exponential distribution whose values are incrementally shifted by +0.2 is used to follow how the KL divergence responds to the distributions becoming more and more dissimilar. The plots of the changing KL divergence metrics obtained from the integration and from the quack package are very different. The really weird one is the numerical integration based KLint_metric_forward where the KL divergence increases then decreases, and that doesn't make sense to me. Is something off with the integration code? Frankly, couldn't figure out exactly what it does, I just modified it to work with the kde class object variable names.

```
#library(ks)
#devtools::install_github("knrumsey/quack")
#library(quack)
#Create a distribution to study, as well as its kde to integrate
z1_private <- rexp(1000, 1)
d1 <- kde(z1_private)
set.seed(13)

#Integration function
kld_base = function(x,y,...){
  integrand = function(x,y,t){
    f.x =  approx(x$eval.points,x$estimate,t)$y
f.y =  approx(y$eval.points,y$estimate,t)$y
    tmpRatio = f.x *(log2(f.x) - log2(f.y))
    tmpRatio = ifelse(is.infinite(tmpRatio),0,ifelse(is.na(tmpRatio),0,tmpRatio))
    return(tmpRatio)
  }
  return(integrate(integrand,-Inf,Inf,x = x,y = y,stop.on.error=FALSE)$value)
}

#For loop to incrementally change the distribution
KLint_metric_forward <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
KLint_metric_backward <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Jeffreyint_metric <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
deltaX <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
for (i in 1:10) {
  z1_private_altered <- z1_private+ 0.2* (i-1)
  deltaX[i] <- 0.2*(i-1)
  d1_altered <- kde(z1_private_altered)
KLint_metric_forward[i] <- kld_base(d1, d1_altered)
KLint_metric_backward[i] <- kld_base(d1_altered, d1)
Jeffreyint_metric[i] <- (KLint_metric_backward[i] + KLint_metric_forward[i])/2
}

#Visualize how the integrated KL divergence changes
plot(deltaX, KLint_metric_backward)
lines(deltaX, KLint_metric_forward) #Why is this one this weird while the other is great
lines(deltaX, Jeffreyint_metric)

#This visualizes how the original and later distributions look
plot(d1)
lines(d1_altered[["eval.points"]], d1_altered[["estimate"]])

#Repeat for the kde function based KL divergence
KL_metric_forward <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
KL_metric_backward <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Jeffrey_metric <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
deltaX <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
for (i in 1:10) {
  z1_private_altered <- z1_private+ 0.2* (i-1)
  deltaX[i] <- 0.2*(i-1)
  KL_metric_forward[i] <- kld(z1_private, z1_private_altered)
  KL_metric_backward[i] <- kld(z1_private_altered, z1_private)
  Jeffrey_metric[i] <- (KL_metric_backward[i] + KL_metric_forward[i])/2
}

plot(deltaX, KL_metric_forward,col="red")
lines(deltaX, KL_metric_backward,col="red") #Why is this one this weird while the other is great
lines(deltaX, Jeffrey_metric, col="red")
```